# Gnuplot plot visualization inside paraview 2D view

Tags: gnuplot, paraview

I have plots made with some Gnuplot scripts already. Is there a way to introduce Gnuplot plots in a Paraview 2D view?

The dirty way that I've found is: first I generate a png image and import it later from Paraview and finally visualize it in a 2D view.

Does anyone know a better alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Paraview has a Python view which allows to define a python script for creating 2d plots ( http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/704 , http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/588)

Maybe you can use a python interface to gnuplot (for example http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/ ) and insert your script in the Python view properties.